R data.tree from XML
I am seeing deprecation warnings in data.tree (v 1.1.0 with R 4.4.0, xml2 1.3.6, XML 3.99-0.16.1) and having issues accessing the data associated with XML elements.
The data.tree instance was created as follows:
library("XML")
library("xml2")
library("data.tree")
# abbreviated sample XML that reproduces problems
xml = '
<Result>
    <Record>
        <Deployment schemaLocation="http://tethys.sdsu.edu/schema/1.0 tethys.xsd">
            <Id>ALEUT01-KS</Id>
            <Project>Aleut</Project>
            <DeploymentId>1</DeploymentId>
            <Site>KS</Site>
            <Cruise>Aleut01</Cruise>
            <Platform>mooring</Platform>
            <Instrument>
                <Type>HARP</Type>
                <InstrumentId>ALEUT01-KS</InstrumentId>
            </Instrument>
            <SamplingDetails>
                <Channel>
                    <ChannelNumber>1</ChannelNumber>
                    <SensorNumber>1</SensorNumber>
                    <Start>2010-06-03T00:00:00Z</Start>
                    <End>2010-07-20T11:15:00Z</End>
                    <Sampling>
                        <Regimen>
                            <TimeStamp>2010-06-03T00:00:00Z</TimeStamp>
                            <SampleRate_kHz>200</SampleRate_kHz>
                            <SampleBits>16</SampleBits>
                        </Regimen>
                    </Sampling>
                </Channel>
            </SamplingDetails>
        </Deployment>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Deployment schemaLocation="http://tethys.sdsu.edu/schema/1.0 tethys.xsd">
            <Id>ALEUT03-BD</Id>
            <Project>Aleut</Project>
            <DeploymentId>3</DeploymentId>
            <Site>BD</Site>
            <Cruise>Aleut03-BD</Cruise>
            <Platform>mooring</Platform>
            <Instrument>
                <Type>HARP</Type>
                <InstrumentId>ALEUT03-BD</InstrumentId>
            </Instrument>
            <SamplingDetails>
                <Channel>
                    <ChannelNumber>1</ChannelNumber>
                    <SensorNumber>1</SensorNumber>
                    <Start>2011-05-31T00:00:00Z</Start>
                    <End>2012-08-26T19:51:15Z</End>
                    <Sampling>
                        <Regimen>
                            <TimeStamp>2011-05-31T00:00:00Z</TimeStamp>
                            <SampleRate_kHz>200</SampleRate_kHz>
                            <SampleBits>16</SampleBits>
                        </Regimen>
                    </Sampling>
                    <DutyCycle>
                        <Regimen>
                            <TimeStamp>2011-05-31T00:00:00Z</TimeStamp>
                            <RecordingDuration_s Offfset_s="0">300</RecordingDuration_s>
                            <RecordingInterval_s>600</RecordingInterval_s>
                        </Regimen>
                    </DutyCycle>
                </Channel>
            </SamplingDetails>
        </Deployment>
    </Record>
</Result>'

dom <- xml2::read_xml(xml)  # parse
doc_list <- xml2::as_list(dom)  # data.tree expects a list
t <- data.tree::as.Node(doc_list)  # Convert to data.tree

When I attempt to navigate the data.tree, it is unclear how to access the text associated with the elements, and I see deprecation warnings:
# Expected to be able to access Start time 2011-05-31T00:00:00Z in 
# Result/Record/Deployment[2]/SamplingDetails/Channel/Start
> t$Result$children[[2]]$Deployment$SamplingDetails$Channel$Start
  levelName
1     Start
Warning messages:
1: In (function ()  : 'Node$fieldsAll' is deprecated.
Use 'Node$attributesAll' instead.
See help("Deprecated")
2: In (function ()  : 'Node$fields' is deprecated.
Use 'Node$attributes' instead.
See help("Deprecated")

I assume this is likely to be pilot error on my part, any help would be appreciated.

xml %>% read_xml %>% xml_find_all("//Start/text()") %>% as.character()

Thank you, I know that the xml2 package can be used, I was hoping to be able to use data.tree navigation here.

Did you try to use the functions the deprecated warning messages advise? Read the docs on those recommended methods then re-write attempt of t$Result...
